# Sinatra app running on Heroku has RegexpError

Tags: ruby, regex, sinatra, heroku

My sinatra app runs fine locally (see screenshot below) but when I push it to heroku it crashes and I get this error

```
RegexpError - undefined (?...) sequence: /(?<=(LIST ALL SELECTED ))\w/:
```

The line of code where the occurs is

```
match = data.match('(?<=(LIST ALL SELECTED ))\w')[0]
```

What I am trying to do is capture the next letter directly after 'LIST ALL SELECTED '

Any insite to what this means would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: That's what i'm guess. I'd like to know for sure one way or the other. Also I'd like to know if there is a way that heroku can support it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's what's called a positive lookbehind.  Ruby doesn't support them, but if that's the whole regexp, you don't need it.

```
match = data.match(/LIST ALL SELECTED(\w)/)[0]
```

Ben (look down, in the comments) says your regexp with the lookbehind does indeed work on Ruby 1.9.2.  Heroku must be using 1.8.6 or 1.8.7, which doesn't have lookbehinds.

Comment: No offence, but it doesn't work on Ruby 1.8.  Also, upgrade from rc2.

Comment: What error do you get when you try the regex AR posted? Does it work any better passed as a String ('') than as a Regex (//) ?

Comment: @lxs I rewrote the code to eliminate the positive lookbehind, pushed to heroku and it worked fine. From what I could find on the internets heroku is running on Ruby 1.8.6.